# What to do if you didn’t know about ghusul?

Tags: salat, ghusl

When I was 15 I tried having intercourse. I was young so I did not know about ghusul. A friend told me I had to shower to pray so I showered but I never performed the proper ritual to cleanse. It’s been 7 years and I have not had intercourse since and I pray everyday. Is my prayer valid?

Comment: You haven't bathed in 7 years? Ghusl is just washing of the whole body, a thorough shower should have fulfilled all the requirements. Any further rituals are Sunnah not obligatory, so prayer is valid even if you missed them.

Comment: Obviously I have bathed but I thought you must shower in a specific way… So are you saying my prayers are valid?

Comment: The only thing you should do is, once you know about your ignorance is to learn and do it better or as it should be.